# Disable Downloading Cached FTP File

Tags: vba, powershell, ftp, cache-control, winscp

I've got a PowerShell script that I call from VBA using Excel. The script uses WinSCP to download some datetime-named FTP and SFTP files and saves them with a static filename, overwriting the old file, on a network drive location.

The script works on first run, but after that it loads the same cached version of the file. The workaround is to change the cache settings in IE to check for newer versions of stored webpages 'every time I visit the webpage'.

The macro is used by several people and is accessed using a variety of computers. Is there a way around this that I can incorporate in my code, either in VBA or PS so they don't have to remember to go into IE to change their settings?

Script is called from VBA:

```
 Call Shell("powershell -executionpolicy bypass & ""H:\FTP\FTP.ps1""", vbHide)
```

Script:

```
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
    $localPath = "H:\Worksheets\FTP"
    $remotePath = "/outgoing/data/LatestData/"
    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::ftp
    $sessionOptions.HostName = 
    $sessionOptions.UserName = 
    $sessionOptions.Password = 

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Get list of files in the directory
        $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

        # Select the most recent file
        $latest = $directoryInfo.Files |
            Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory} |
            Where-Object {
                [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -eq ".nc1" -or
                [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -eq ".ky1" -or
                [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -like ".tn*" }

        Group-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) } | 
            ForEach-Object{ 
                $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
            }

        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($latest.Name)
        "GetExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'" -f $fileName, $extension 

        if ($latest -eq $Null)
        {
            Write-Host "No file found"
            exit 1
        }

        $latest | ForEach-Object{
            $extension = ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name)).Trim(".")
            $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $_.Name), "$localPath\$extension.txt" ).Check()
        }

        $stamp = $(Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm")
        $filename = $stamp.subString(0,$stamp.length-6)
        $session.GetFiles(
            ($remotePath + $fileName),
            ($localPath + $fileName + "." + $stamp)).Check()
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: How's IE related to the script? What does it mean "load" in respect to the script? Do you mean "downloads"?

Comment: I don't know how IE is related, apparently it sets the rules for http/ftp caching for the operating system. All I know is that when a user changes the setting in Internet Options a new file gets downloaded and the problem goes away.

Comment: WinSCP does not use any system cache. Your question does not make sense. Show us your code.

Comment: I added code to my post

Comment: 1) What `GetFiles` call does not work? 2) Enable logging (`$session.SessionLogPath = "C:\path\to\session.log"`) and append a log file from working and non-working run and describe the differences. 3) What's the `Group-Object` good for? It does not seem to do anything. It does not have any input. 3) In some places you treat the `$latest` as a scalar variable, and in some as an array

Comment: 4) The second `GetFiles` call is most probably wrong. You are missing a backslash between the `$localPath` and `$fileName`. It just cannot work => Your script must be failing => Displaying some errors => And you didn't tell us!